# Will this snippet of code lead to memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I have this snippet of code, I'm not sure if it's performant. Will this lead to any memory leak?

```
renderComponent(component) {
  let timeout = null;

  component.on("rerender", () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      // do stuff
    });
  });
}
```

An "unrender" method looks like this:

```
unrenderComponent(component) {
  component.off('rerender');
}
```

Component extends EventEmitter ([eventemitter3](https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3))

`component` will be unreachable at some point, but I wonder if the `timeout` inside `renderComponent` will cause memory problems.

I've been thinking a solution could be to store the timeout inside component, this way: `component.timeout`. So when `component` is collected, so is the `timeout`.

Comment: No, the `timeout` variable itself is not a problem. (It's just an integer anyway). The actual problem, if any, would be the timer itself that has been scheduled, and the closure that `// do stuff` built.

Comment: `unrenderComponent` might also want to call the `clearTimeout`. But is absolutely unclear from your question where and how you are calling these functions.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. `renderComponent` is called first, `unrenderComponent` is called after some time. `unrenderComponent` does need to call `clearTimeout`. Thank you for spotting that out.